# How to make redirect a User after they have submitted an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

This is the View that I want the user to login on and then leave:

```
@model IEnumerable<TerminalHost.Models.deviceInfo>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#myTerminal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 550,
        height: 350,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 650
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 600
        },
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                    //Get he content from the input box
                    var uName = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value;
                    var pWord = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value;
                    var ipAddress = document.getElementById("ipAddressInput").value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Terminal/terminalLogin",
                        data: { userN: uName, passW: pWord, ipAd: ipAddress},  // pass the data to the method in the Terminal Contoller
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
                        },
                        error: function (e) { alert(e); }
                    })
                },
            "Cancel": function (e) {
                $("#myTerminal").dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


    $("#terminalAccess").click(function form() {
        $("#myTerminal").dialog("open");
    });
});

function onSuccess() {
    $("#myTerminal").dialog("close");
}
</script>

<div id="myTerminal" title="Terminal Login">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="passwordInput" id="usernameInput" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordInput" />
    <label for="ipAddress">Ip Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="ipAddress" id="ipAddressInput" />
</div>
```

This is the View that the user will go too:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Terminal";
}
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cmdSend").click(function () {
        // Get he content from the input box
        var mydata = document.getElementById("cmdInput").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Terminal/processCommand",
            data: { cmd: mydata },  // pass the data to the method in the Terminal Contoller
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                // we need to update the elements on the page
                var existingHtml = $(".terminal").html();
                $(".terminal").append("</br>" + "->" + mydata + "</br>" + data);
            },
            error: function (e) { alert(e); }
        })
    });
});
</script>
<h3>Terminal for device: *Device name*</h3>
<ol class="round">
<li>

    <article>
        <div class="terminal" style="overflow-y: scroll;" ></div>
        <div class="terminalInputArea">
            <div class="inputBox">
             <input id="cmdInput" /><button type="button" id="cmdSend">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>

</li>
</ol>
```

and this is the controller that I want the data to be sent to:

```
 public class TerminalController : Controller
{
    SSH ssh = new SSH();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult terminalLogin(string userN, string passW, string ipAd)
    {
        ssh.username = userN;
        ssh.password = passW;
        ssh.ipAddress = ipAd;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Terminal") });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Terminal");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string processCommand(string cmd)
    {
        ssh.cmdInput = cmd;
        String info = ssh.SSHConnect();
        info = info.Replace("!", "<br>");
        return info;
    }

    public ActionResult Terminal()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

I didn't include the model as I figure its not the problem but I can add it. The model is called SSH.cs

Comment: Updated code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725155/issue-setting-values-in-model-using-ajax-and-then-redirecting-to-a-new-page) But with an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use          "window.location.href = data.redirect;"

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Terminal/Terminal",
                    data: { userN: uName, passW: pWord, ipAd: ipAddress},  // pass the data to the method in the Terminal Contoller
                    success: function (data) {
                       window.location.href = data.redirect;

                        //????? I'm assuming the redirect goes here.
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (e) { alert(e); }
                })
```

Your class should be like this

```
public class TerminalController : Controller
{
SSH ssh = new SSH();

   [HttpPost]
public ActionResult terminalLogin(string userN, string passW, string ipAd)
{
    ssh.username = userN;
    ssh.password = passW;
    ssh.ipAddress = ipAd;

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Terminal","Your controller", new {parametername_Username=userN, parametername_Password= passW,parametername_IpAddress = ipAd }) });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Terminal");
}

[HttpPost]
public string processCommand(string cmd)
{
    ssh.cmdInput = cmd;
    String info = ssh.SSHConnect();
    info = info.Replace("!", "<br>");
    return info;
}

public ActionResult Terminal()
{
    return View();
}
```

}

data.redirect is the URL that you should have to send from controller. if you need more details please let me know.

add following element to your view 
     @Html.HiddenFor( m => m. username)
     @Html.HiddenFor( m => m. password )
     @Html.HiddenFor( m => m. ipAddress )
on to your view
cheers

Comment: I had tried that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725155/issue-setting-values-in-model-using-ajax-and-then-redirecting-to-a-new-page) but I noticed that when I redirected the info I set for the username, password and Ip was nullified.

Comment: Would you have any Idea how to make the data carry over when the user is redirected?

Comment: if i understood what you asked , you need to know how to create redirect on the data isn't it? its a property of  return json object. let me know that you need a sample code.

if i did't get your problem could you elaborate it more. big pardon for that.

Comment: I basically want a user to enter login details for the page that they are about to redirect too(I figured out how to perform the redirect). however when they redirect the details they entered are lost, I found that the data is lost when the redirect occurs, I would like to know if there is a way to maintain the data while the redirect occurs.

Comment: If you know a better way of taking the value for the uname,pword and IpAddress and storing it until the user leaves the page I'm all for it. I kinda have 9 hours left to submit this project and this is my last issue so I'm up to try anything at this point

Comment: Ok let's do this.. if it's only user name and password why can't you attached to the redirect URL which you sending from json object. I think you'r post method have those information isn't it.

Comment: How would I do that, attach the uname and pword to the URL. Oh and by the way thank you so much for helping! If you need any more code that I have in the project feel free to ask

Comment: I'll update the code in this page to show you what I have thus far

Comment: i think you should return this from your terminal function 


      "return Json( new { Success = true, redirect = Url.Action( "method that you want to redirect", "Controller", new { Username = username, password = your encrypted password ) } );"

Comment: I've updated the code that has any connection to this

Comment: have you tried my previous comment code should have to return it on that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54000/discussion-between-valmangul-and-peo).